# How to get a link to an old question of mine, possibly deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I am looking for an old question of mine that (I believe) asked about the largest number of different kinds of satellites in one payload. I also believe I included a yellow-room photo of the Kanopus-V-IK "agglomeration" of satellites.

I believe that the question might have been auto-deleted due to lack of activity, or was perhaps manually deleted for other reasons. I suppose it could still exist but I can't seem to find it in my list of questions or in searches.

I can not find the question now, and I'd like to make edits to it or use it to ask a new one. Either way I'd like to access the images, text, and links contained in the question.

What else might I try to get a hold of a link to this question, deleted or not?

I believe it would have contained an image similar to (if not identical to) the one below, from eoPortal's [MKanopus-V-IK 1 (Kanopus-Vulkan-Infra-Krasny-1)](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/k/kanopus-v-ik-1). See also:

- https://spaceflight101.com/soyuz-kanopus-v-ik/video-payload-stack-fairing-encapsulation/
- https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2017/07/soyuz-2-1a-launches-kanopus-v-ik-70-satellites/

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226224/228367 It's unusual for you not to be able to see your own deleted posts, but it's not unheard of.

Comment: I'll take a look at that, thanks, it will be a bit of a challenge to go back several hundred days but maybe there is a way to automate I remember the question didn't have many votes and could be zero, so that will be a challenge as well. I think there is a 60 or 90 day limit for the `deleted recent question` list. If it was deleted by a bot for zero votes and no activity (I've seen something like that happen before, don't remember what it's called) then if it had appeared, it would only be there there for a few months.

Comment: This plus [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318155/303080) together suggests I may have to break down and just learn some SQL.

Comment: I already tried to stackexchange data Explorer. It doesn't show deleted questions at all for space exploration.

Comment: @called2voyage In this case I was going to try to see if the data explorer might be able to automate the search of the reputation tab (described in your link), which is only currently giving me about 3 days per page meaning I'd have to view perhaps 100 pages. But maybe the data explorer can't be used in that way.

Comment: As you have 2k, just run a search for `deleted:1 satellites` or something along those lines, which will show you only your own deleted posts that otherwise match.

Comment: @NathanTuggy thanks! It's the interface that I'm stuck at right now. I don't really have a good feel for running scripts which means that *I simply don't know how* or at least I can't remember. It's very embarrassing, and I don't let other people know of this; so please just keep it between you and me. Thanks ;-)

Comment: @NathanTuggy I didn't know about the "deleted:" flag on searches. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Nathan's method (search for `deleted:1 satellites`), I was able to find it.

Here is the question I believe you were looking for:

https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22516/58

Comment: I've [renewed interest](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56945905#56945905) in getting this undeleted.

Comment: @uhoh No problem. It didn't seem like there was any opposition to it, so I figured I'd give it another chance to see if it catches attention.